# how to show value text rather than id of dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: model-view-controller, dropdown

I have a create view in which i have static dropdown list populated with some pre-defined values for the year , Now on listing i want to show the year text like 2012,2014,2019 rather than their values 1,2,3 How to achieve that remember i have static dropdown data is not coming from database below is the code

```
<td>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>item.Year_Passed, new List<SelectListItem>
{
new SelectListItem{ Text="Select Year", Value = "0" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2000", Value = "1" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2001", Value = "2" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2002", Value = "3" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2003", Value = "4" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2004", Value = "5" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2005", Value = "6" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2006", Value = "7" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2007", Value = "8" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2008", Value = "9" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2009", Value = "10" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2010", Value = "11" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2011", Value = "12" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2012", Value = "13" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2013", Value = "14" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2014", Value = "15" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2015", Value = "16" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2016", Value = "17" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2017", Value = "18" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2018", Value = "19" },
new SelectListItem{ Text="2019", Value = "20" },
}, item.Year_Passed, new { @class = "well well-sm", @id = "Year", @disabled = "disabled" })
```

item.YEar_passed is coming from Db it is saving year id value not text

Comment: What is the issue? It's not very clear in your question. With this code your dropdown will already show year in dropdown and not the code which is what you want.  Also Year_passed will be bound to Value of SelectListItem so for this case "1","2" etc . If you want to save year in database then keep the value also as year i.e "2019""2020" instead of 1,2,

Comment: I am saving the values in db as 1,2,3 but on index view i want to show the text like 2013,2017 not 1,2 how to achieve that , My dropdown is static not getting data from db